# set-transient-map oddity for emacs -nw

Tags: elisp

I have this tester code:

```cl
(defvar dbg-vec nil)
(defun foobar ()
  (interactive)
  (message "%S" (setq dbg-vec (this-command-keys-vector))))
(set-transient-map '(keymap (left . foobar)
                     (t . foobar)
                     (97 . foobar)))
```

It works as expected in the GUI. But for `emacs -nw` it gives strange behavior.
If I press <kbd>left</kbd> after evaling the last statement, I get:

- error "No previous locations for find-tag invocation"
- `dbg-vec` becomes `[27]`, although the key code for left is 113.

Note that it still works as expected if I press <kbd>a</kbd>.
What could be the source of this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: In `emacs -nw` keys like the arrow send a sequence of key strokes. In the case of "left" `ESC [ D` is emitted.

Comment: OK, I could run that through `input-decode-map` myself, if `set-transient-map` doesn't want to do
this automatically. But how do I access `ESC [ D`? As you see, I only got `ESC` (27).

Comment: I think you only get `ESC` because your keymap is removed once that has been handled. One way to do this is to use the `KEEP-PRED` parameter which will make stay active a bit longer. Another would be to hook yourself into another keymap that is handled after `input-decode-map` (depending on what you are trying to do, of course).

Comment: Or, you can try to add a nested entry for `ESC [ D` using something like `(27 . (?[ . (?D . foobar)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right fix is to not use a catchall `t` binding.  These are very tricky to use and basically can't be made 100% reliable.

The whole motivation behind `set-transient-map` was actually to avoid using `t` bindings (which are typically used to exit from some transient mode, so they just take the event and then want to "unread" it by putting it on `unread-command-event` but "unreading" can't be done reliably).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using `t` just to issue the warning and throw away the input, so there's no problem
with un-reading.

The issue is that binding `left` is different in GUI and -nw versions. But only if `t` is set.

Comment: As I said, such catch-all bindings are tricky to use, and this SO question is just another proof of it.  Throwing away a random event is not simple because it can be part of a sequence of events, such that dropping the first changes the meaning/effect of the subsequent ones.

Comment: OK, I've worked out a way to do what I want without `t`. But now I have to use my own function instead of `set-transient-map`. And I have to port that function to all recent Emacs versions.